# Prove that two commitments are commitments to the same value

Tags: discrete-logarithm, commitments, schnorr-signature, blind-signature

Let $x$ be the secret value, $(n,a,b,c)$ a public key, $(n_C, g, h)$ the commitment public key. Furthermore let $r, r_C$ be two random numbers.

Define $C = g^x h^{r_C} \bmod n_C$, $C_x = a^x b^r \bmod n$.

I want to prove that $C$ and $C_x$ are commitments to the same value without revealing $x, r$ and $r_C$.

My idea is:

Proofer $P$ chooses a random $s$ and sends $t = (a^s \bmod n) (g^s \bmod n_C)$ to the Verifier $V$.

$V$ chooses a random $c$ and sends it to $P$.

$P$ sends $\tilde{s} = s + c*x$ and $\tilde{b} = b^{cr} \bmod n$, $\tilde{h} = h^{cr_C} \bmod n_C$ to $V$.

$V$ checks whether $(a^{\tilde{s}} \bmod n)(g^{\tilde{s}}\bmod n_C)\tilde{b}\tilde{h} = tC^cC^c_x$.

I guess that will not work, because there is missing some modulo in the end.
The question is how to combine the modulos of $n$ and $n_C$. Can I use the gcd of $n$ and $n_C$?

EDIT:

Or maybe there is an easier way, because this will not just prove that the commitments are about the same value but also proves knowledge of x?

---

EDIT 2:

Here is an attempt to fix my problem:

Proofer $P$ chooses a random $s$ and sends $t_1 = a^s \bmod n, t_2 = g^s \bmod n_C$ to the Verifier $V$.

$V$ chooses a random $c$ and sends it to $P$.

$P$ sends $\tilde{s} = s + c*x$ and $\tilde{b} = b^{cr} \bmod n$, $\tilde{h} = h^{cr_C} \bmod n_C$ to $V$.

$V$ checks whether $(((a^{\tilde{s}} \bmod n)\tilde{b}) \bmod n) (((g^{\tilde{s}}\bmod n_C)\tilde{h})\bmod n_C) = ((t_1C^c_x)\bmod n)((t_2C^c)\bmod n_C)$.

This should work, right?

Comment: Trvially; easiest way would be to reveal blinding scalars. The verifier still cannot get the other value unless he broke the DLP.